# Heroku Automated Certificate Management not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku

I have a domain, `example.com`. It's running on hobby dynos in Heroku, so I figured I would enable Heroku Automated Certificate Management. I've set up Heroku like so:

```
=== example Custom Domains
Domain Name      DNS Target
───────────────  ─────────────────────────────
example.com      example.com.herokudns.com
www.example.com  www.example.com.herokudns.com
```

My DNS settings are:

```
CNAME Record www example.com.herokudns.com.
URL Redirect Record @ https://www.example.com Unmasked
```

However, neither the apex domain (example.com) or the www domain (www.example.com) work when I access the domain.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd reach out to Heroku themselves. Automated Certificate Management is a new product for them, and I'm sure they'd be eager to help get you up and running.

Comment: Hi, Could you fix this issue?. Thanks, I'm getting this error too

Comment: Alexander Giraldo, after a lot of back and forth between Heroku Help and me, which resulted in only the www domain working but not the apex domain, I ended up using my previous Cloudflare configuration and turning off ACM. Super frustrating.